# Using an AAR inside an SDK used inside an application

Tags: android, sdk, aar

I am writing an SDK which depends on an AAR file. This AAR file is included in the SDK using the following:

```
// Inside the SDK's project level build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
// Inside the SDK's module level build.gradle
build.gradle {
    implementation(name:'test', ext:'aar')
}
```

The SDK then performs a Gradle sync without issue. The SDK is then included in a sample application:

```
// Inside application's settings.gradle
include ':sdk'
project(':sdk').projectDir = new File('/path/to/sdk')

// Inside applications module level build.gradle
dependencies {
    api project(':sdk')
}
```

However, the sample application now fails to perform a Gradle sync and displays the following:

> Error: Failed to resolve: :test:

Why is this occurring?

Comment: As it stands, consumers of `sdk` have no way of automatically getting `test`. Ideally, you would put both `test` and `sdk` in an artifact repository, so that transitive dependencies can work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why is `test` not transitive? Since `sdk` uses `test`, one would assume that any project using `sdk` would have no problem resolving `test`. Other then uploading `test` to an online repository, are there any other workarounds?

Comment: "one would assume that any project using sdk would have no problem resolving test" -- why? For all the app knows, `test` is on a hard drive on a computer that is 6,000 miles away, buried under a volcano, protected over by an ancient Incan deity. Y'know, to pick a location at random. :-) When you're not using a repository, there is no metadata (e.g., POM file) for transitive resolution.

Comment: "Other then uploading test to an online repository" -- it doesn't have to be online. Use `mavenLocal()`. However, if `sdk` is going to be used by anyone other than you, then you really need to plan on a repository that everyone can get to. Or, distribute both `sdk` and `test` and have apps manually depend on both.

Comment: If `app` depends on a local `sdk`, and `sdk` depends on `test` (which is included in the `/libs` dir), why does that cause a problem? Let's say I build `sdk` into an AAR for others to include in their `app`. Wouldn't that AAR contain all the stuff from `test`?

Comment: "Wouldn't that AAR contain all the stuff from test?" -- unless `flatDir` works differently than other types of dependencies, no. An *app* contains all of `implementation` dependencies. An AAR does not. Personally, I avoid `flatDir`, so perhaps it has different characteristics than I am expecting.

Comment: @CommonsWare Follow up question: the `test` library represented in the example (the `.aar` library needed in the `sdk`) is closed source and distributed manually as an `.aar`. Considering that there is no way to use this `.aar` in our `sdk` (as noted in the comments above), what should the vendor of this third party `.aar` do to accommodate the fact that it is being used in an `sdk`?

Comment: "Considering that there is no way to use this .aar in our sdk" -- you could have licensees of your SDK also license the `test` library from its vendor, then put both their `dependencies` closure. "what should the vendor of this third party .aar do to accommodate the fact that it is being used in an sdk?" -- well, ideally, they would publish the library via an artifact repository. If you also published your library via an artifact repository, apps could use both repositories, and Gradle could pull in `test` via transitive dependencies.

Comment: As mentioned the `test` library from the third party vendor is closed source. How could they host it in such a way that only the `sdk` has the ability to pull artifacts from it? Additionally, if both the third party vendor's library (`test`) and the sdk (`sdk`) are hosted in an artifact repository, would the consumer of  `sdk` have to define the location of both artifact repositories (`test` and `sdk`) in their `build.gradle`?

Comment: "How could they host it in such a way that only the sdk has the ability to pull artifacts from it?" -- they can't. Presumably, though, you're not the only licensee, and so the question is how well they can limit it to all their customers. There may be authentication options here, but I have never explored them. There's always "security by obscurity", in that nobody else should know the URL of the repository. "would the consumer of sdk have to define the location of both artifact repositories (test and sdk) in their build.gradle?" -- yes, assuming that they are separate repositories.

Comment: @CommonsWare The goal is to allow consumers of `sdk` to declare only `sdk` as a dependency. The vendor would also not like to open source their code. Apart from getting the vendor to send the source code of their library so that it may be directly included in `sdk`, are you suggesting that there is no way to include it within those constraints? I thought private repos were a thing (https://jfrog.com/article/private-repositories/).

Comment: There is no official support for a "far AAR" packaging, where you include the contents of `test` into `sdk` itself. There may be independent toolchains that offer this. As the saying goes, YMMV. Plus, that may violate your license for `test`. But if you have the rights to bake `test` into `sdk`, you should have the rights to distribute `test`. In that case, you could put both `test` and `sdk` into your own artifact repository. And if you *don't* have the rights to redistribute `test`, then your goal is unachievable from a licensing standpoint, let alone a technical one.